# Cannot reset password for users created in cognito console

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Im creating a login for a CMS to a website for a small business using the React javascript framework. Obviously random people can't just register their own details so at present i am attempting to manually create the users (a max of 5 at present) within the cognito console. I have the majority of the authentication workflow established (using just the Auth library from Amplify) with INITIAL forced password reset, forced MFA TOTP authentication and successful access to the CMS on login. However the Forgotten Password functionality despite my best efforts just refuses to work and I believe I've narrowed it down to cognito itself.

Short of trying every damn combination of a user pool and created user to get this to work, I provide the following when creating a user from the cognito console -


1. Username (must be email)

2. Temporary Password

3. No phone or phone verification

4. Email and tick email verification

For the userpool conditions the following is the current working setup (minus the forgotten password functionality)


1. Email Address required for sign in

2. Standard attributes are given name, family name, phone number

3. MFA is required

4. Second factor is Time Based One Time Password

5. Email is selected as the attribute to be verified (which i believe to be a moot point as this is manually done when creating user)

6. No SMS role provided, required or necessary

7. I have verified an email address with SNS and have this entered in the FROM and REPLY-TO fields for email customization and have selected the use of using Amazon SES below these customization fields.

This is the entry point of my Authentication workflow, identifying where in the workflow the user is at and acting accordingly.

```
await Auth.signIn(email, password)
  .then(user => {
    setFetching(false);
    switch (user.challengeName) {
      case "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED":
        switchComponent("Verify", user);
        break;
      case "SMS_MFA":
      case "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA":
        switchComponent("ConfirmSignIn", user);
        break;
      case "MFA_SETUP":
        switchComponent("MFASetup", user);
        break;
      default:
        history.push({ pathname: "/" });
        break;
      }
   })
```

Everything works as it should for the most part. MFA workflow displays a nice QR Code for the user to utilize and confirm using their Authenticator of choice, NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED is submitted via the following -

```
const handleSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (noErrors()) {
    setFetching(true);
    await Auth.completeNewPassword(inputs.user, inputs.newPassword, {
      email: inputs.email,
      phone_number: inputs.phoneNumber,
      given_name: inputs.givenName,
      family_name: inputs.familyName
    })
      .then(() => {
        setFetching(false);
        switchComponent("MFASetup", inputs.user);
      })
      .catch(err => onShowDialog(err.message));
    setFetching(false);
  }
};
```

From what i can tell, nothing is out of the ordinary here. However any attempts to initialize the forgotten password flow after successfully authenticating past the REQUIRE_PASSWORD_RESET, even from the cognito console and i am presented with "Cannot reset password for the user as their is no registered/verified email or phone number", this is despite enabling the "verified email" when creating the user from the cognito console.

By using the aws command line I can force the verification however this to me is just infuriatingly unintuitive when the enabling of this when creating the user should take effect. Im at my wits end here and I have clients waiting for this software. Any help would be greatly appreciated in this instance. I apologize for any redundant content in this question I just want to make sure I cover everything the first time. Regards.

Comment: So I've spent the best part of the last week trying to troubleshoot this problem, spend the last half hour piecing together this question, then on a hunch I remove the email key/value pair from the Auth.completeNewPassword function and the damn thing works....everything works.....I certainly hope the time I wasted isn't in vain and perhaps someone else learns from my mistake and comes along this question....sorry for the waste of time folks. Excuse me while I go bang my head repeatedly against something hard....